# How redirect Amazon EC2 Machine url to a domain?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, host

I know it might sound unconventional, as it's normally other way around. But because of a unique situation I'm facing this issue. The issue is that I want to redirect **ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/xyz** (development url) to **https://xyz.example.com** (production url - a sub-domain). The config for other way around is working well. I went through apache docs and tried some settings, but it's not taking effect. Below are the config and server details.

```
#ssl setting

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
 ServerName www.xyz.example.com
 ServerAlias xyz.example.com
 DocumentRoot /www/html/example
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl-cert/example.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl-cert/example.key
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

#redirection setting

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/xyz
 Redirect permanent / https://xyz.example.com/
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Server details:
**Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS,
Apache2**

'A' record setting is already done and working.

I have limited knowledge in server configuration. I did some research but still not able to figure out the problem in the config.

Please advice me where I'm doing wrong.

Best Regards

Ranjeet Sengar

Comment: Give us some more info. What do the apache logs look like? If you do a `curl -v http://ec2-xxxxxxx/xyz`, what do you get?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nathaniel.
As you asked, the access.log shows the date and time, 'GET /xyz' with 200 status code and browser engine info. And error.log doesn't show any error.
Also when I do **curl -v http://ec2-xxx/xyz**, it gives me the index.php's html content. I'm guessing that there is something I'm missing in the virtualhost config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all why you are using Public DNS Name of EC2 instead of creating your own some.example.com and creates a A record with Elastic IP of EC2

Second, in the above config, you are using server name as

```
www.xyz.example.com which should be xyz.example.com
```

Try changing the ServerName and restart the apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Hello Vikash, thanks for the answer. I tried changing server name, but still the issue is there. Also I've already created **some.example.com** with proper A record with Elastic IP of EC2, I just want the Public DNS Name of EC2 to redirect to my sub-domain, which I know is very unconventional.